# Get FeatureLayer Attribute by Clicking

Tags: feature-layer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.8. My goal is to get the Census tract ID value of the clicked Feature in a FeatureLayer and display the ID value in an alert box. I got stuck when trying to use Query/QueryTask to fetch the value. My code goes here:

```
require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/layers/GroupLayer",
  "esri/widgets/LayerList",
  "esri/tasks/support/Query",
  "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
  "dojo/on",
  "dojo/domReady!"
],
function(
  Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, GroupLayer, LayerList, Query, QueryTask, on
) {
    var map = new Map({
      basemap: "topo"
    });

    var view = new MapView({
      center: [-91.05, 30.5161109],
      zoom: 11,
      container: "viewDiv",
      map: map,
    });

    // Generate link to Census tract details
    view.when(function() {
      on(view, "click", displayTractID);
    });

    function displayTractID(event) {
      // TODO
    }

    // Define popup template and get feature layers
    var census2000Template = {
      title: "Census 2000",
      content: [{
        type: "fields",
        fieldInfos: [{
          fieldName: "TRACT",
          label: "Tract",
          visible: true
        }, {
          fieldName: "POPULATION",
          label: "Population",
          visible: true,
          format: {
            digitSeparator: true,
            places: 0
          }
        }]
      }]
    };

    var census2000Layer = new FeatureLayer({
      url: "http://services.arcgis.com/KYvXadMcgf0K1EzK/ArcGIS/rest/services/Census_2000/FeatureServer/0",
      outFields: ["*"],
      popupTemplate: census2000Template
    });

    // Add feature layers to a group layer
    var censusGroupLayer = new GroupLayer({
      title: "Historic Census",
      visible: true,
      visibilityMode: "exclusive",
      layers: [census2000Layer]
    });

    map.add(censusGroupLayer);
  });
```

I need to fill the TODO part with Query/QueryTask. Any help or sandbox samples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [hitTest(screenPoint)](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#hitTest) method, to search for graphics at the clicked location, after you get the `screenPoint` from the `view-click` event.

```
function displayTractID(event) {
  var screenPoint = {
    x: event.x,
    y: event.y
  };

  // Search for graphics at the clicked location
  view.hitTest(screenPoint).then(function (response) {
    if (response.results.length) {
      var graphic = response.results.filter(function (result) {
      // check if the graphic belongs to the layer of interest
        return result.graphic.layer === census2000Layer;
      })[0].graphic;

      // do something with the result graphic
      console.log(graphic.attributes);
    }
  });
}
```

I've also created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/katahV/pen/BPrNRb?editors=0011) with the entire source code.